# How to access the results of mongodb find() operation using mongodb javascript native driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a database in mongodb and I'm connecting to it through NodeJS and mongodb native driver. I'm trying to write a javascript code to print in the browser the information retrieved from the database through db.foo.find() operation.

I am currently able to print the value part of the json data. However, i need to print the key part as well.

Example : json data { key1:v1, key2:v2 ....}
i need a way to access the key1 and key2 values through javascript code without knowing them prehand??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(json).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [for...in syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the keys of an object.